# how can we create the same hashcode value for 2 identical objects using lombok?

Tags: java, singleton, lombok

I am trying the singleton design pattern. I know that service1 and service2 have the same hash values when we manually implements and overrides the equals and hashCode methods. But I want to do this through lombok, not manually. But I want hashcode values to be generated via Lombok. When I use the @EqualsAndHashCode annotation top of the class, service1 and service2 hashcode values are output differently. How can I ensure that the hash values of service1 and service2 are the same using Lombok? I used @EqualsAndHashCode but it didn't do what I wanted. I also used @EqualsAndHashCode.Include and it still didn't work.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final PaymentService service1;
    private final PaymentService service2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        log.info("service1 hashcode " + service1.hashCode());
        service1.setAmount(100L);
        service1.setPaymentStatus("success");
        log.info("service2 hashcode " + service2.hashCode());
        log.info("service2 amount " + service2.getAmount());
        log.info("service2 status " + service2.getPaymentStatus());
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class PaymentService {
    private long amount;
    private String paymentStatus;
}

@Component
public class PaymentConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "singleton")
    public PaymentService getPaymentService() {
        return new PaymentService();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your class with [`@EqualsAndHashCode`](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode):

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class PaymentService {
```

Comment: I tried way that you explain but didn't work as expected

Comment: @expelliarmus care to ellaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation in Lombok generates `equals` and `hashCode` methods based on the fields in your class. In your case, since you have two different instances of `PaymentService` (service1 and service2), they have different field values, resulting in different hash codes.

To ensure that service1 and service2 have the same hash code when their values are the same, you can use it like `@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"amount", "paymentStatus"})`.

Comment: I know that service1 and service2 have the same hash values when we manually implemen and override the equals and hashCode methods. But I want to do this through lombok, not manually.

Comment: You can use this annotation like “@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"amount", "paymentStatus"})”

Answer (score 0):

Everything with your question seems wrong.

It starts with the title:

> *how can we create the same hashcode value for 2 identical objects using lombok?*

First: your code doesn't contain "2 identical objects". You are using Spring singleton beans to create **one and only one** `PaymentService` object and your code therefore has **only one** `PaymentService` object. This object is referenced by the two fields `service1` and `service2`, **but there is only one object**.

Second: Lomboks `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation was created for exactly this: create a `hashCode()` method that creates *the same hashcode value for 2 identical objects*. It does this by taking into account all the fields of the object.

Your test code:

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) {
    log.info("service1 hashcode " + service1.hashCode());
    service1.setAmount(100L);
    service1.setPaymentStatus("success");
    log.info("service2 hashcode " + service2.hashCode());
}
```

only shows that if you change the fields of an object the hashcode for that object changes.

Specifically it cannot show that the hashcode from `service1` is different from the hashcode of `service2` (hint: they are not because **there is only one object**) because you change that object between the two calls and that just shows that the hashcode changes if the object changes.

To show that the hashcode for `service1` is different from the hashcode for `service2` **you must print** both hashcodes before changing the object (and you may want to print both hashcodes after changing the object):

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) {
    log.info("hashcode before changing the object");
    log.info("service1 hashcode " + service1.hashCode());
    log.info("service2 hashcode " + service2.hashCode());
    log.info("changing the object");
    service1.setAmount(100L);
    service1.setPaymentStatus("success");
    log.info("hashcode after changing the object");
    log.info("service1 hashcode " + service1.hashCode());
    log.info("service2 hashcode " + service2.hashCode());
}
```

---

> *When I use the @EqualsAndHashCode annotation top of the class, service1 and service2 hashcode values are output differently.*

Yes, with your sample code the hashcode values are output differently - because between those two output **you modified the object by changing fields** and changing the fields leads to a different hashcode value.

But this is not because Lomboks `@EqualsAndHashCode` is broken - it is because your sample code (especially the part where you want to show that the hashcode changes) is broken.

---

Your sample code behaves in this way:

- Your house is painted white
- you take a picture of your house
- you paint your house green
- you take a picture of your house

And then you ask someone "why in the first picture is my house white when it is green in the second picture?"

Well it is because you painted your house green!?